# The return type / return value is part of the signature of the method?

Tags: c#, methods, return-value, method-signature

C# documentation [Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) states

> Methods are declared in a class, struct, or interface by specifying
> the access level such as public or private, optional modifiers such as
> abstract or sealed, the return value, the name of the method, and any
> method parameters. These parts together are the signature of the
> method.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int InstanceMethod1()
    {
        return 85;
    }

    public static string StaticMethod1()
    {
        return "Bar";
    }
}
```

In regards to the above excerpt, by "return value" is it referring to the "return type" of the method? Thus, the return type of a method (in the above examples `int` and `string`) is considered part of the signature of the method?

Note, I did read following side note "A return type of a method is not part of the signature of the method for the purposes of method overloading. However, it is part of the signature of the method when determining the compatibility between a delegate and the method that it points to."... However, my above example has nothing to do with method overloading.

Comment: The signature _must_ contain a return `type`. "The return value" is 100% the incorrect term, only the `type` is defined in the signature.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Hey chandler thanks comment. In regards to my above example (which is has nothing to do with method overloading and has nothing to do with a delegate) would you say the return type of the methods (int and string) are considered part of their signature?

Comment: user Kyleruss states that in regards to my above example,  the return types of the methods are NOT part of their signature. Would love to hear your opinion on the matter as well.

Comment: I agree that a method must include a return type however based on the on the C# language spec, the return type is not considered part of the method signature. As mentioned in my answer, there are some cases where the compiler does consider the return type as part of the method signature such as delegates.

Comment: I agree with Chris regarding the ambiguous use of the 'return value' and 'return type' terms in the MSDN documentation, although the authors do appear to be using the terms interchangeably however I agree it is incorrect and confusing.

Comment: To clarify if the type is part of the signature or not, the type cannot be changed either through overloading or overriding. So the type is part of the conceptual signature or prototype, but not part of the signature that can be considered by the compiler for overloading. You will notice it is also not part of the signature when used in comment references like <see/> or <seealso/>. In all other contexts the return type is considered part of the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of a method must strictly follow the return type of its method so you could technically use the two terms interchangeably when talking about method signatures which it looks like they've done in the excerpt, albeit confusing.

In the case of method overloading the return type is not considered part of the method signature as the compiler cannot determine on return type alone which methods to use and as such the return type is not included in the method signature. For example consider the following overloaded methods where only the return type differs:

```
public int GetResult() { }
public double GetResult() { }
```

If we were to call this method, how would the compiler know which method to use?

```
var result = GetResult();
```

However as the language definition states: the method name, number of generic types, number of and type of each formal parameter and out/ref/value parameters are part of the method signature when overloading so for example if you wanted to overload then you could do:

```
public int GetResult() { }
public int GetResult(int x) { }
```

There are cases where the return type of a method is considered part of the signature such as delegates since the method must have the same return type as the delegate declaration. As per the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/):

> In the context of method overloading, the signature of a method does not include the return value. But in the context of delegates, the signature does include the return value. In other words, a method must have the same return type as the delegate.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply... So if I understood you correctly, outside of the context of method overloading the return type / return value (both terms used interchangeably as you stated) is considered part of the signature of the method..... But what about outside of the context of a delegate? **In my above example, it also has nothing to do with a "delagate" pointing to the methods I declared. Thus, is the return type of a method considered part of its signature, outside of the context of a delegate?** I'd love to hear back from you thanks :)

Comment: No the return type would not typically be considered part of the method signature including the example you gave, as mentioned there are some cases where it is considered part of the signature such as delegates as it needs to be in order to ensure the method return type matches the delegate declaration. In my example the method signatures would be: `GetResult()` and `GetResult(int)` and in yours they would be `InstanceMethod1()` and `StaticMethod1()`

Comment: I have accepted your solution as the answer because according to the current information in the C# docs, it does give off the impression that "only in the context of a delegate is the (return type / return value) of a method part of its signature."... However, the docs are not explicit/clear enough for me to totally agree with your opinion on the matter. I'm not saying you are wrong but because the docs are not explicit/clear enough, I would not rule out the notion that the return type is part of the signature of the method outside of the context of delegate. As shown in my above example.

Comment: The MSDN docs aren't particularly clear on this aspect of the spec but there's plenty of external resources that echo what is mentioned in the MSDN docs