# Can C# look at return type to determine if a member method is unique or not?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have two methods where the only difference is the return type but the C# compiler does not like this. C# seems only capable of seeing if the input parameters are different when determining if a method is unique or not? I assumed with polymorphism, I'm under the impression the return type is a part of the signature. Is there a way around this?

```
public interface IReportMiddleware
{
    GridReader GetQueryData(SqlConnection conn, string sqlCmd, DynamicParameters parameters);
    IEnumerable<ReportData> GetQueryData(SqlConnection conn, string sqlCmd, DynamicParameters parameters);
}
```

**ERROR:** IReportMiddleware already defines a member called GetQueryData with the same parameter types.

Comment: The return value type isn't part of the definition of a member.  From the C# 7.0 language specification [15.6.1 Methods - General](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#1561-general): *The name, the number of type parameters, and the formal parameter list of a method define the signature (§7.6) of the method. ... **The return type is not part of a method’s signature...***  See e.g. [The return type / return value is part of the signature of the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71182489/3744182).

Comment: _"I'm under the impression the return type is a part of the signature"_ - But if that were true, how would the compiler understand which method you want to use from `GetQueryData(connection, myCommand, myParameters)`?

Answer (score 3):

The [C# spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#1531-general) says

> The name of a method shall differ from the names of all other non-methods declared in the same class. In addition, **the signature (§7.6) of a method shall differ** from the signatures of all other methods declared in the same class, and two methods declared in the same class shall not have signatures that differ solely by in, out, and ref.

And in [section 7.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#76-signatures-and-overloading) it says

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the number of type parameters, and the type and parameter-passing mode of each of its formal parameters, considered in the order left to right. For these purposes, any type parameter of the method that occurs in the type of a formal parameter is identified not by its name, but by its ordinal position in the type parameter list of the method. The signature of a method specifically **does not include the return type**, parameter names, type parameter names, type parameter constraints, the params or this parameter modifiers, nor whether parameters are required or optional.

So it's explicitly excluded in the spec. This is despite the fact that .NET allows such methods to be declared directly in IL.

The logic is probably clear: in C# syntax it's impossible to differentiate at the call site which of the two methods you want to call.